# How to duplicate another horizontal scrolling given the first example?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here is a demo
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GM00VH226ISH

The scroll for the first line is working but not for the second one.
I have tried declaring another variable called scroll_2 but it doesn't work.
Please provide a running example for code in your solution.

```
   scroll_2.addEventListener("mouseup", () => {
        isDown = false;
        scroll_2.classList.remove("active");
    });
```